# Set the index from given array of object having another array of object

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a data structure which looks like ,

```
const rows = [{"rowType": "firstRow", "data": [{"value": "first val"}, {"value": "10"},{"value": "20"}]}, {"rowType": "sizedRow", "data": [{"value": "sized val"}, {"value": "20"},{"value": "30"}, {"value": "40"}]}]
```

Now, here I am iterating this data as

```
{rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                  <TableRow key={rowIndex}>
{row.data.map((item, index) => (
   <input type="text" tabindex = //This value needs to be set.

 </TableRow>
 ))}
```

Now, I am trying in such a way that

```
[0][1] => tabindex should be inner loop index value
[0][2] => tabindex should be inner loop index value
[0][3] => tabindex should be inner loop index value
--- goes on

 here [0] (outer loop ndex) indicats the rowIndex and [1] indicates the index (inner loop)
```

So here its kind of matrix .

So, How can I set the tabIndex to the index.

Comment: `tabindex={index}`?

Comment: If I do this then all the elements in the inner loop will get the 1 id and which  I am not looking ,  it would be like [0][1] => 1 ,  [0][2] => 1 ... goes on but, what I am looking is 
0][1] => 1 0][1] => 2 ..

Comment: @ganesh 0][1] => 1 0][1] => 2 .. ?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress it would be like, for rowsIndex 0 then in the inner loop , for first element it should be set to 1, second element it should be 2 , for third 3 so it would become in case o matrix if we represent

[0][0]  (as index will also be 0 so  +1) it would be 1 and it goes till last element in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere before `return` statement:

```
let tabindex = 0;
```

later in the `return` statement:

```
{rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
  <TableRow key={rowIndex}>
    {row.data.map((item, index) => (
      <input type="text" tabindex={++tabindex} />
    ))}
  </TableRow>
))}
```

Comment: No this wont work as it will make [1][0] to 2 and [2][0] to 5

Comment: and which is desired result, @ganesh ?

Comment: it would be like, for rowsIndex 0 then in the inner loop , for first element it should be set to 1, second element it should be 2 , for third 3 so it would become in case o matrix if we represent [0][0] (as index will also be 0 so +1) it would be 1 and it goes till last element in the inner loop.

Comment: Sorry @ganesh , but I never was so far to be clear. Could you please retry with an example? Please provide the matrix and the desired result.